# In javascript, how to get a class name from a td cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In javascript, how to get a class name from a td cell?

example:

```
<td class="ColumnHeader" style="text-align:right;" >
```

class "ColumnHeader" is a class inside css, how could i retrieve it from css and changed the width size in javascript?

Comment: Are you trying to modify a stylesheet with JS or modify the `class` attribute of a DomNode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select all the `<td>` elements via `getElementsByTagName()` and iterate over them looking for the `className`:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i<tds.length; i++) {

  // If it currently has the ColumnHeader class...
  if (tds[i].className == "ColumnHeader") {
    // Set a new width
    tds[i].style.width = new_width;

    // Or set a different class which defines the width
    tds[i].className = "someOtherClass";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't really change the width of the css class programatically, but you can change it on the element:

```
td.style.width = newWidth;
```

To get the class name from an element, use:

```
var className = td.className;
```

Comment: td.style.width = td.style.width +/- newWidth ?